# Excel VBA Sql: ADODB.Recordset - GetRows(index) column analog

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I am new in VBA Sql, and I wrote an SQL-query and got ADODB.Recordset as result.

I can get row values by index:

```
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst.ActiveConnection = cn
rst.Open cmd

Dim myValues As Variant

myValues = rst.GetRows(1)
```

Is there any method to get column values by name or index?

In my task I firstly need to know number of rows in my recordset, then create an array `MyArr` with this size, iterate over rows in column `columnname` (or with index `indexname`), calculate some values using values in recordset's column and then write the calculation result into `MyArr`.

How could I do it fastly and correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a recordset can be read only once, from beginning to end (well, there are methods to open a recordset in a way to access the records in any order, but usually this is not needed and it is also not supported from all data sources).

The easiest way to fetch the data from a recordset is to use `GetRows` without parameter, it will return the values of all rows and columns and put them into a 2-dimensional array. You just need to know that the first index of the array is the column index and the second index is the row index. Note that the lower index of both dimensions is 0.

```
Dim myValues
myValues = rst.GetRows   ' Read all data into 2-dimensional array

Debug.Print "# Cols: " & LBound(myValues, 1) & " to " & UBound(myValues, 1)
Debug.Print "# Rows: " & LBound(myValues, 2) & " to " & UBound(myValues, 2)

Dim myArr()
ReDim myArr(0 To UBound(myValues, 2))
Dim row As Long
For row = 0 To UBound(myValues, 2)
    ' myArr(row) = MagicCalculation(myValues(0, row), myValues(1, row), myValues(2, row))
Next row

' to list all field names:
Dim col As Long
For col = 0 To UBound(myValues, 1)
    Debug.Print col & ". field: " & rs.Fields(col)
Next col
```

Answer (score 0):

To get values directly (rather than sending the whole recordset to an array) recordsets are designed to use a "cursor".  Once you get the cursor to the desired row, the .value property for each field becomes the field's value in that row.  Then you can use field names or the field index, such as `rs.fields("DateOfBirth").Value` or, for shorthand, `rs!DateOfBirth.Value`.

The cursor can be moved to a specific location in various ways, including methods that move the cursor forwards and backwards (`rs.MoveNext`, `rs.MovePrevious`) and properties that can be set directly (`rs.AbsolutePosition` or `rs.BookMark`).

These can then also be used with `rs.GetRows`.  If you set the cursor to the `rs.AbsolutePosition = 10`, then `rs.GetRows(1)` will return just that row as an array.  GetRows also has parameters to select fields by name or ordinal position and specify how many rows to return.  See the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15).